# Linking an existing account to a Google account

Tags: support

I created my account a while ago by creating my own username and password and would now like to link this with my Google account so that when I sign in I don't have to type in (an remember) a separate username and password. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you click on "my logins" from [your profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/26069/user26069), you should be able to add a new openid sign-in. Choose Google and follow the prompts.